# Get query result from NpgsqlDataReader

Tags: c#, npgsql, dbdatareader

This is my function:

```
public int gtCountCertificatByExercice()
{
    DataTable resDataTable = new DataTable();
    DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();
    string query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS nb_cert " +
                   "FROM crs_certificat " +
                   "WHERE id_exercice = " + IdExercice + " ";
    NpgsqlConnection conn = dbConnection.Conn;
            
    NpgsqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    Int32 nbCertByExercice = 0;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            nbCertByExercice = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("" + nbCertByExercice);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    conn.Close();
    return nbCertByExercice;
}
```

and I always get this error: "Specified cast is not valid" !!
but when I use this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    nbCertByExercice = Int32.Parse(reader["nb_cert"].ToString());
}
```

It works fine !!
I also have the same problem with dateTime type!!
What should I do do get directly the type of the field ?

Comment: What is the value of `reader["nb_cert"].ToString()`?

Comment: Are you sure? So `COUNT(id) as nb_cert` returns `"int"`? What if you execute that query on the database?

Comment: COUNT return int right ??

Comment: it gives me the number of certificats in database !!

Comment: What is `s` if you put this line in: `string s = reader["nb_cert"].ToString();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use ExecuteScalar for your query?

replace

```
 NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read())
 {
     nbCertByExercice = reader.GetInt32(0);
 }
```

with

```
nbCertByExercice  = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

you should use reader when you have rows to control, [executeScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to take the first value of the first column of the query, [executenonquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) for operations like Insert, delete

**UPDATE**

Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) you can see that the return type of `COUNT` is `int` and not `INt32`. When you perform

```
reader.GetInt32(0);
```

you get InvalidCastException because it doesn't do explicit conversion of type ([refer here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx)).

> The exception that is thrown for invalid casting or explicit
>   conversion.

otherwise when you perform `Int32.Parse` it always try to convert and if it fails trows an exception.

In your case the value is always eligible to be converted to an int32 but `reader.GetInt32` can't know because of differents types; on the other side `Int32.Parse` makes an attempt and it is successful.

Comment: And what's the difference ?

Comment: Sorry still the same problem !!

Comment: thnx for the explanation :)